# SWT TableViewer multiselection without Ctrl

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm using a TableViewer and I want to it perform like when I hold CTRL key. I mean if I click a row, it must be added to selection and not replace current selection.
I probably need to do this manually in selection listener. But may be there's a better (more convinient) way?

Comment: Are you using `SWT.MULTI` selection tag?

Comment: Yes, but I need to hold CTRL to select multiple lines

Comment: Could you post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableviewer wraps a Table, which multi-select behavior is platform-specific, that means you cannot disable that. If you want to implement your own multi-select behavior you have to implement your own table-widget which does not depend on the Table widget from SWT. The [Composite Table](http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/compositetable/compositetable.php) should be a good starting point...

Answer (score 2):

How about adding the SWT.CHECK attribute when constructing the table so the table entries will be selected with a checkbox?

Comment: Yes, that was the second idea I came with :) But I was just curious if what I have described here is possible.